# In express.js, req.files is undefined

Tags: node.js, upload, express

I try to upload a png to my node.js server, but every time `req.files.avatar` is called, an error appears and says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined`.

Comment: What does the code that uploads the file on the client side look like?

Comment: Do you use bodyParser as a middleware?

Answer (score 19):

The problem was that I haven't write `enctype="multipart/form-data"`in the form. That's why req.files was undefined.

Comment: not really, i have enctype="multipart/form-data" but got the same error

Comment: For me (Express 4.17.1) this was exactly the case.
Seems like busboy middleware is hooked only to multipart headed requests.

Answer (score 16):

Also I think you have to include your bodyParser **before** any instructions to use app.router or static middleware. After some trial and error this is the order that works for me.

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.port || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/server/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.locals.pretty = true;
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.bodyParser( { keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: __dirname + '/app/uploads' } ));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'super-duper-secret-secret' }));
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/app/public' }));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app/public'));
});
```

Comment: I totally forgot body parser and this resolves my problem. Thx!