# express-fileupload request.files is always undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I want to upload a file from my browser and `POST` it to an Express.js application that then downloads the file using [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload).
Client-side javascript code so far:

```
// fires on onclick event of a button
function upload() {
    // only get one file (you also only can select one in the input field)
    file = document.getElementById('file').files[0]

    // check if a file is selected
    if (file.length == 0) {return}

    // add file to a form
    form = new FormData()
    form.append('file', file)

    // POST form using fetchAPI
    fetch('/upload', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: form
    })
}
```

The client code completes without any errors. The request even shows up on my network-tab.
The request from the client arrives at this controller:

```
import express from 'express'
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload'

export function uploadPOST(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    if (req.files) {
        console.log('put')
        const file: fileUpload.UploadedFile = req.files.file as fileUpload.UploadedFile
        file.mv(`${settings.storage.path}/${req.app.get('username')}/${file.name}`)
    }
}
```

In the debugger, req.files is always undefined but the application throws no errors.
I also added `fileUpload` and `bodyParser.json()` to my middleware.

Other people got the same problem and [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014017/in-express-js-req-files-is-undefined) it but the answers didn't resolve my case.
I also followed this tutorial: https://attacomsian.com/blog/uploading-files-nodejs-express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the `Content-Type` header in the `POST` request. The browser will set it for you. If you manually set the `Content-Type`, express will not recognize the request as `multipart/form-data` and cannot set the `files` property of the request.

Also don't forget to add the `{ createParentPath: true }` option to the `express-fileupload` middleware, as this will allow express to create paths and access paths outside of the working directory.